# I am add frame tag in my code then I am getting this error?

Tags: javascript

I am add Youtube emended code then I am getting this error.

Anyone can tell me how we can handle this error.

[image]

Comment: Switch off your adblocker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer from [teemu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1169519/teemu) in comments section:

Switch off your adblocker